# Detecting Touch Devices With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch, detect

I've spent a fair bit of time on the web looking at the various ways of detecting a touch device, but this surprisingly complicated issue does not seem to have a definitive answer. Based on [this article](http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/), I've decided to pursue the following approach.

```
// Run immediately and assign a global variable (touch_enabled) so it is accessible anywhere.

// First try to detect (not entirely reliable)
window.touch_enabled = !!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window);

// Overwrite/set touch enabled to false on mousemove
$(window).on('mousemove', function() { window.touch_enabled = false; });

// Overwrite/set touch enabled to true on touchstart
$(window).on('touchstart', function () { window.touch_enabled = true; });
```

I'm wondering if anyone can point out any issues with this method. I have not field tested it yet and will be doing so right away, but any second opinions would be appreciated.

Below is a quick demo.

```js
window.touch_enabled = !!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window);
$(window).on('mousemove', function() { window.touch_enabled = false; });
$(window).on('touchstart', function () { window.touch_enabled = true; });

setInterval(function() { $('.output').text(window.touch_enabled); }, 200);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Touch Enabled = <span class="output"></span>
```

Comment: Btw, I used a timer in the demo to test if a touch device switches to an input device (plugging a mouse into a MS Surface tablet, for example). Anyone with one, please let me know how it works!

Comment: You might consider a library like Modernizr to help you with this.

Comment: I would read this, weep, the reconsider your approach. https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/548

Comment: @Andy - I'm trying to avoid loading an entire library to do a simple touch detect. Plus it seems that Modernizr is not reliable either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that in general the distinction has to (or even should) be made beforehand - coding for both events makes things work in all circumstances and it will be more reliable:

```
$('#element').on('mousedown touchstart', function() { ... });
```

But some cases can occur where the origin of the event has to be known, for example when a mouse or touch position has to be processed. Then a distinction can be made when the event happens :

```
$('#element').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {

var touch = e.originalEvent.touches;
var pageX = touch ? touch[0].pageX : e.pageX;

....

});
```

Hope that helps, it has worked well for me so far.

Comment: In my case, I actually need to know before hand - I'm building custom form elements (like a select menu) that works/displays a bit differently depending on if you're using touch or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is sensible given the limitations of browser APIs today. I have similar code that might suggest a few changes:

1. track window.pointer_enabled separately (don't assume touch and pointer are mutually exclusive)
2. use jQuery's `.one()` to bind to the touch/mouse events only once
3. fire "touch detected" and "mouse detected" events so you can adapt UI when you are surprised after page load to find an input method

   ```
   // assume event handlers mean we have touch input
   window.have_touch = !!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window);

   // bluntly assume only one input method
   window.have_pointer = !window.have_touch;

   // react to reality
   $(window).one('mousemove', function(e) {
     window.have_pointer = true;
     $(window).trigger('found_pointer');
   });
   $(window).one('touchstart', function(e) {
     window.have_touch = true;
     $(window).trigger('found_touch');
   });
   ```

Comment: Using the .one() method is interesting. However, what happens if you're on a Surface tablet and you plug and unplug a mouse?

Comment: Different OSes and browsers address this differently. The modernizer library has some pretty good discussion about it. There's no obvious right way, so that' sway I look for movement to detect a "second" input method.